# Faster Logstash to Elastic indexing from flat files

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, bigdata

I'm indexing JSON files out of S3 into Elastic with Logstash's S3 input plugin running on an EC2 T2.Medium instance. This works fine, but it's incredibly slow. I'm looking for some advice on faster ways of doing this as I realise multithreading with multiple Logstash instances out of S3 isn't an option.

My source data is actually in Google Big Query tables so if there was a way I could index from there that would be great, but I can't find a plugin or obvious way of doing this. I've been exploring the idea of pushing the BigQuery data into Redis first, but with the volume of data i'm looking to index i'm concerned this adds extra overhead, technical and cost wise that could be avoided.

My Elastic cluster is very simple, single node / single shard. I ran a test on a multi-node cluster to see if there were any indexing speed increased and it stayed the same. I'm using Elastic's hosted cloud service, formerly Found, so i'm not sure if that would have any bearing on this.

At present i'm happily indexing around 5M rows a day, albeit slowly. I'm aiming to be able to index around 100M per day in as quick a time as possible. At the current EPS, it'll take days!

Any general pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat)

Comment: One simple way is you can run multiple instances of logstash. And you need to find the bottleneck - is it pulling data from s3 or pushing data into elastic through logstash.

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi with no sincedb file when indexing from S3, how would the second instance of Logstash know where to start? Wouldn't this risk duplicates?